# Cannot cause $(this).find("a").click(); to fire using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, thickbox, double-click, gridviewrow

I have a small question which should be very easy for the jquery experts out there. 
I am trying to follow http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2010/01/page-languagec-autoeventwireuptrue.html to be able to perform an action on gridview row double click. I can redirect to another page fine (as shown in the example) but I cannot cause the $(this).find("a").click(); to fire. Below is my GridView markup.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsCustomers" CssClass="datagrid"
        GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Customer_ID" PageSize="3"
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnRowCommand="gvCustomers_RowCommand"
        OnRowDataBound="gvCustomers_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" CommandName="showVehicles" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Customer_ID") %>'
                        ></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Sorry No Record Found.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I just cant make it work as the author has suggested: 
/* or you could have a hidden LinkButton in the row (Text="" or not set) that you could trigger. Make sure you set the CommandName="Something" and CommandArgument="RecordId" */

on the OnCommand of linkButton, I have my server side method which I would like to fire.
Any ideas will be most apprecited.

Thanks, 
Ali

Comment: can you show me the html that the asp code generates?

Comment: Where's your javascript? `this` is relative, without knowing where you're coming from it's a blind guess.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script below your link is not clicked because the `window.location` is set. Reading what the blog post is say you either set the `window.location` or use `$(this).find("a").click();` but not both.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selected = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#gvCustomers").find("tr").click(function(){
            $(selected).removeClass("selected"); $(this).addClass("selected"); selected = this;
        });
        $("#gvCustomers").find("tr").dblclick(function(){
            var Id = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
            //window.location = "/CustomersVehiclesWebSite/Default2.aspx?record=" + $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
            $(this).find("a").click();
        });
     });
     function doPostBack(element) {
     tb_remove();
     setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'' + element.name + '\',\'\')', 500);// 500ms given to thickBox to remove itself
     }
</script>
```

Comment: removed window.location but no joy. 
Is there an alternative way of achieving the same thing? i.e. calling a server side method from gridview row double click?
OR 
displaying a popup with details of the row that was double clicked?

Basically I haven't used JavaScript and JQuery a lot so I am not too comfortable with these.

Comment: The technique in this blog post looks convincing though as I have already displayed jquery popups from server side methods.